# Discord.js - Get Message from Interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

`client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {}`

The interaction class has lots of properties like `channel`, `member` and `id` but it doesn't have a `message` property.

Is there a way to get the message from an interaction or will I have to use a event listener on message? And if so, how would I use this with slash commands?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user input by just using the base class `interaction`. However, the content is not visible, but you can view it by passing it through an api endpoint or something similar, its kind of weird for me but i'm sure there is an explanation for that.

The best way is to use `interaction.options`, so you'll need to add at least one option in your application command.

For example

```
// /test as your Application command 
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.commandName === 'test') {
          const message = interaction.options.data
          console.log(message)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slash commands have their own type of message. I don’t believe they have an id, delete button, edit button or lots of things most messages do. This means you will not be able to get the "message" from a slash command. From buttons however, they do emit `INTERACTION_CREATE` but has a little more info. I don’t remember for sure, but I think you can use something like `interaction.components`. I am not completely sure, but if you want, click a button and log the interaction into your console to see the unique button info like this

```js
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {
{
console.log(interaction) //will be long!
//…
})
```